# OSGi fragment bundle merge of headers

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, maven-bundle-plugin

If I create a fragment bundle and add a new header entry under the maven-bundle-plugin instractions. Will that new entry get merged with the host bundle headers list at the runtime?..

Comment: You can try it out in a couple of minutes and answer your own question ;-).

Comment: I tried that before posting the question and host bundle header list doesn't contain that, so just want to make sure its the default behavior or a mistake in my fragment bundle.. :)

Comment: Ok. I think your fragment bundle was good.

Answer (score 0):

A bundle shares its classloader with its fragment bundles. That is all.

Bundle.getHeaders() always shows the headers defined for that specific bundle. The headers of fragment bundles are not merged to the headers of host bundle.